# Jquery load() not working in a each loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the following code, i make a loop on all iframe tags. In my page there are actually 2 iframe tags and the block of code below works only for the first iframe tag met :

```
$("iframe").each(function()
{   
    if (!!$(this).attr("src"))
    {
        if ($(this).attr("src").indexOf("youtube") != -1)
        {
            $(this).before("<div id='iframeContent'></div>");
            $( "#iframeContent" ).load( "/NoThirdPartyCookies.html #thirdPartyCookies");
        }

    }

});
```

For the second iframe, the div which has for id "iframeContent" does not contain anything as if the load() didn't return anything.
Can anyone say me what's wrong ?

PS: both iframes have an "src" attribute and contains "youtube". I already checked this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because you can't use the same id (in this case `#iframeContent`) on multiple elements. You will be better off using classes (`.iframeContent`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! it works well with classes !